# Why is there a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-studio, nullpointerexception

My code that is causing a problem is in my app's MainActivity. In the onCreate method there is a Thread that runs a method called uploadImage(). This then returns a Map and is set in uploadedImage (a Map instance). After the thread, the **public** Map uploadedImage is null. (It throws a `NullPointerException` on the line that states so). Does anybody know why uploadedImage is perceived as null outside of the Thread? Thanks!

```
...
public Map uploadedImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //only perform if there is a network connection
    if(isNetworkAvailable()) {

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //try to upload image
                    uploadedImage = uploadImage();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();

        TextView txtURL = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        String url = uploadedImage.toString(); //NULLPOINTEREXEPTION HERE
        txtURL.setText(url);
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Not an expert in threaded Java, but my guess is that the Thread doesn't have a chance to assign uploadedImage before you access it.

Comment: BECAUSE you make it as a new thread. Use asynctask then put them in onPostExecute(). or put them in your thread and call the start with runOnUiThread() <-- i have not tried this before

Comment: The way you're doing it now, you have no guarantees `uploadedImage` will be with the right value when you hit `String url = uploadedImage.toString();`. Do you see that? I don't know what kind of operations you do in `uploadImage()`, but you probably wanna set a callback to know when your task has finished.

Comment: Educate me: What is the point of using a Thread here if your code cannot proceed until that Thread has finished executing?

Comment: it might be not related to your question but use piccaso jar for image upload. Don't reinvent the wheel again,if it's for a learning curve then great

Comment: I am actually using Cloudinary's image API which requires an asynchronous task or similar. I think the above people are right

Comment: The reason I need a Thread or an AsyncTask is because I get a NetworkOnMainThreadException from uploadImage() if I don't. How can I use an AsyncTask with onPostExecute to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an ASyncTask and placed the Map in the String "url" in the onPostExecute override method.
The above people that said the Task was not finished executing were correct. Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Then `uploadedImage` is `null`. Also, you should make that call synchronously since this call

```
String url = uploadedImage.toString();
```

clearly requires that `uploadedImage` be initialized and not `null`;

```
if(isNetworkAvailable()) {
    try {
        //try to upload image
        uploadedImage = uploadImage();
        TextView txtURL = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        String url = (uploadedImage != null) ? 
                uploadedImage.toString() : "null";
        txtURL.setText(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, look into [Loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html), they "make it easy to asynchronously load data in an activity or fragment". Defining _nice_ default values for your views, then updating them as more data becomes available can provide a more responsive (or enjoyable) experience for your users.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the code for method uploadImage()? Check what is happening inside there and why it would return null?